# Does the backing store of Spark really matter?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is the following statement true?  The backing store (relational DB, NoSQL, JSON files) used in Spark is not very relevant because Spark will load all of the data into memory and then perform analytics.

I've come to this conclusion after reading the Spark, SparkSQL and GraphX documentation available online at spark.apache.org.  The general pattern I see is to first load the data, next define what you want to do (ML, Graphx, Map), and then execute.  Is my statement true and if not why?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the underlying storage matters.

First of all, each storage has its own weaknesses and benefits. HDFS, for example, is optimized for cases when one needs to load big portions of data (i.e. high throughput). At the same time, HBase is a better choice for low-latency tasks. The overall performance of your use cases will depend on the storage.

Apart of that, Spark SQL is capable of pushing down some filters. This means that the data can be prefiltered at the storage and only a relevant portion of it will be transmitted to Spark. This has a dramatic impact on the performance of your computations. For instance, prefiltering will happen if you use Elasticsearch, Apache Parquet or a lot of other technologies as the underlying storage. On the contrary, you won't have this functionality with JSON files.